# How to create dataframe of the keys and values from a series of dictionaries

Tags: python, json, pandas

I read the json data into dataframe and the first column has data in below format:

```
0     {'name': 'Mark Vande Hei', 'craft': 'ISS'}      10  success

1     {'name': 'Oleg Novitskiy', 'craft': 'ISS'}      10  success
```

How can I create a new dataframe with 2 columns: Name and craft from the above data?

```
url_crew = 'http://api.open-notify.org/astros.json'
crew = pd.read_json(url_crew)
print(crew)
```

Comment: Your input is JSON, and you want to convert it to a dtaframe (properly, not just as one big string). There's no such thing as 'name' element of a dataframe. You're just referring to the structure of the JSON inside your dataframe's column.

Answer (score 1):

```
    url_crew = 'http://api.open-notify.org/astros.json'
    crew = pd.read_json(url_crew)

>>> df = pd.concat([crew.drop(['people'], axis=1), crew['people'].apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)
>>> df = df[['name','craft']]
>>> df
              name     craft
0   Mark Vande Hei       ISS
1   Oleg Novitskiy       ISS
2     Pyotr Dubrov       ISS
3   Thomas Pesquet       ISS
4   Megan McArthur       ISS
5  Shane Kimbrough       ISS
6  Akihiko Hoshide       ISS
7     Nie Haisheng  Tiangong
8       Liu Boming  Tiangong
9      Tang Hongbo  Tiangong
```

Answer (score 0):

Pandas has a really handy utility function, [`pd.json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/io.html?highlight=json_normalize#normalization) to do this.

It accepts a list of dictionaries or a series of dictionaries.

```py
url_crew = 'http://api.open-notify.org/astros.json'
crew = pd.read_json(url_crew)

df = pd.json_normalize(crew["people"])
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
              name     craft
0   Mark Vande Hei       ISS
1   Oleg Novitskiy       ISS
2     Pyotr Dubrov       ISS
3   Thomas Pesquet       ISS
4   Megan McArthur       ISS
5  Shane Kimbrough       ISS
6  Akihiko Hoshide       ISS
7     Nie Haisheng  Tiangong
8       Liu Boming  Tiangong
9      Tang Hongbo  Tiangong
```